# How to invite a user from tenant B to a group call with calling bot for a meeting organized by user from tenant A?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a Calling Azure Bot which is registered with tenant A. The bot got admin consent from tenant B to make/join calls (Application permissions: `Calls.AccessMedia.All`, `Calls.Initiate.All`, `Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All`, `Calls.JoinGroupCall.All`, `Calls.JoinGroupCallAsGuest.All`, `OnlineMeetings.Read.All` and `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All`).

When a user of tenant B schedules an online meeting, I'm able to join this meeting with my bot from a small .NET app using the `Microsoft.Graph`, `Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls` and `Microsoft.Graph.Auth` NuGets.

I'm also able to invite additional participants from tenant B to the ongoing meeting with Graph API `/communications/calls[<callId>]/participants/invite`. But when I try to invite a user from tenant A or any other tenant, the call to invite fails with the following error:

```
Error occurred: Status Code: Forbidden
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: 7505
Message: Request authorization tenant mismatch.
```

Why does this error occur and how can I fix it?
Does the Graph API support this scenario at all?
If not, are there any plans to support it in the future?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is not supported by Microsoft and there are also no plans to support it in the near future. See https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/144